# What do I do if my landlord is scamming me with power?

Tags: electrical

My landlord lives next door, about 50 yards away. He has an in ground pool. The breaker to that and others are on my breaker box outside the home. The breakers are listed WELDER, BASEMENT, UTILITIES, HEAT… etc. I don’t have a welder or a basement. The power company won’t come check it out. My bill is $563. Help.

Comment: Trun off the breakers, and wait

Comment: Check or have your lawyer the rental contract first.  Might be able to turn off those breaker and lock the box, but make sure it is your right(lawyer checks) first.  This might be better on https://law.stackexchange.com/, but they can't give specific advice, only rental law in your local.

Comment: Normally one can write anything you want on breakers. Location , house size, construction and info on heat and other equipment would be necessary to make a guess about your bill ,

Comment: If your landlord is charging you for power based on a utility meter you can turn any breakers off in the panel.  To charge a $ amount for power used usually requires listed equipment, I have a friend that was doing the same he had 2 occupancy’s in one metered address and one renter paid the meter minus the sub panel power usage that was on a power monitor that was not legal for trade , he wanted me to help him but all I could offer was to install the proper equipment, the renter of the small unit got a large judgement because of the equipment but only 25% of the requested you may have similar

Comment: It's a law question, to be sure. If the meter is in your name and you pay the bill, you probably have a case, and you can shut off any and all breakers in the box, unless you allowed some odd language to slip into the lease, and even then the odd language might be illegal (thus, a law question.)

Comment: You only have one meter on your house, right?

Comment: The power company won't usually check anything on the load side of a meter that's operating correctly.

Comment: What is your energy used in a month in kWh? Energy rates vary, it is better to compare kWh. My electric bill is high, I use > 2200 kWh per month in the summer (720 hours in a month, about 3 kW average). I live in a hot climate, have a big house, keep the A/C temp set really low, no gas service, and have an in-ground pool. If your average is much more than 3 kW, something is wrong.

Comment: Gotta agree with know it all. turn off breakers until something quits (like your range, fridge, freezer, outlets, etc. )  then turn them back on one by one.   This probably isn't quite cricket, and I probably shouldn't suggest this, but if you are competent inside electrical panels, pull the cover and get an amp clamp meter and see what is drawing power and when.  YEAH YEAH YEAH, I know this is a sketchy suggestion. The only alternative is to turn off all breakers and see what quits, then turn them on one at a time.

Comment: Do you have a signed lease? What does it state? If this went to small claims court, the signed lease and its contents will be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 9):

The averaged-out continuous use of an average home is 1 KW. More by day, less by night.  Assuming 12 cents a KWH, your house is *averaging* 6.5 KW, or 6.5 times normal!  *That's possible I suppose, if someone was really making super heavy use of A/C, or had  bunch of those [dreadfully inefficient 1-hose portable A/Cs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc) all over the house.*

### Check your power company rate tariff

There are some *wacky* power company tariffs out there, which give you a very favorable rate *if you follow certain rules* but punish you if you don't.  **If you don't know the rules it's really hard to follow them**, so you may be getting brutalized there.

### Step 1: Map your system

Your power system is laid out like:

- Service wires coming from the power company's pole
- An electric meter (YOUR electric meter that you pay)
- One or more service panels (breaker boxes)
- The main breaker in those boxes
- Many individual branch breakers
- Outlets, lights, etc.  with usually more than 1 per breaker

So, the first thing you should do is "map your breakers".  It helps to own a bunch of $1 night lights lol.

Turn off every breaker in the panel.  Now, turn on 1 breaker, and search the house for what powers up.   Write it down in a notebook, and feel free to put stickers on your outlets and switches to indicate which breaker it is.

While you have that breaker on,  you can watch the meter to see how fast the disc turns. Shouldn't turn hardly at all if you don't have appliances turned on in the house.  "I have a smart meter" either there will be a little "marquee light" that indicates progress, or you can push a button to select different menus and it will show you instant watts or kilowatts.

Check your sump pump, radon system and smoke alarms. If possible get a friend to watch them and call out when they start working as you turn on breakers.  You need those systems turned on.

### Step 2: Turn on only the breakers you are using

The point of the above exercise is when you find an outlet is not working, you can go "well that's breaker 6" and go out and turn that breaker on.

Mind you I'm not saying run out and turn off breakers 10 times a day... my main goal is so you can turn them off when you don't expect to use them for awhile (e.g. if you never use the range)... and **so breakers that you never use are simply left off**.

Take notes of how you have left it, so you can spot when ... chipmunks... turn a breaker back on, as I suspect they will LOL.  If it becomes a nuisance, they make breaker locks.

### Consider the possibility that this might be you and your loads

Another nice thing about actually mapping all circuits is that you can easily trace a particular power hog.   If you discover for instance that "wow, that meter really spins when MY air conditioner breaker is on", well that's going to tell you stuff.  You might figure out that the enemy is you lol. The point is, if that's so, now you can figure that out!

### Remember, brinksmanship only goes so far

Most land area in the US is not under "Rent Control".  (but most rental units are).  Rent Control is mainly to stop large rent increases, but to be effective it must also outlaw evictions without good cause.  (otherwise landlords would bypass rent control by evicting anyone who didn't pay market rates).

If you do have rent/eviction control, then you can get the Rent Control Board involved and catch them and bust them, and they will have to let you keep living there and refund any scammed money, possibly tripled if you can get it ruled as fraud.

However if you do NOT live in rent control, nothing really stops them from evicting you - in theory it shouldn't be allowed but in practice it is.  Rent control is like being in NATO - either you are, or you aren't. So whatever you do, you run the risk of having to move out within 30 days if not sooner.  Plan accordingly.

Comment: The cost does seem to be too high for normal use(even if doubled).  Just wondering if there was an electrical fault that a breaker not seeing.

Comment: @crip659 if so, with the main breaker on but all the branch breakers off, the meter should stop spinning.  If it doesn't... gotcha!

Comment: Should have said not causing a breaker to trip.  My mistake for using the wrong words and not meaning what I wanted it to.

Comment: @crip659 interesting possibility, perhaps it will be revealed when OP turns off the breaker (especially if it puts up a fight).

Comment: @manassehkatz *foreheadslap* I did weekly (168hr) not monthly (720hr).

Answer (score 1):

Before we call the lawyers, let get the FACT !

Assuming you have your dedicated power meter
and your landlord has his, before calling lawyers..

Those labels might mean nothing, maybe just a copy of landlord panel without actual consumption.

> He has an in ground pool. The breaker to that and others are on my breaker box outside the home.

Explain that, how do you know ?

Your Monthly bill of $563 would cover 3 homes, with lots of welding going on.

Your yearly bill would be $6,758

If you are not using the **WELDER, or BASEMENT,**

Turn them OFF, to make sure here is no power consumption somehow.

When you turn them off, do you see the Power meter slowing down.

You can do that with all circuit breaker (one by one) while watching the power meter consumption to find out which one is consuming most.

The bill should say for what address is it.

Lets talk about your appliances: (consuption)

Do you have a eDryer that runs every day, do you have eHeater for heating, do you have eFloor heaters, what are the settings on your AC, does it runs all day long.

Comment: Where are you going to walk them too?

Comment: @JACK thank you for paying attention, it was a typo, corrected

Comment: Hey.. we gota have some fun around here.

Comment: On July 4 while his family was swimming and enjoying the day, again he rushed over unannounced to say, “I just need to check this breaker. “